# How to detect if MP4 file is audio or video with fineuploader or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, audio, video, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader and I allow user to upload audio and video files but I'm facing an issue with MP4 files, I've different video players for both audio and video so I need to track if file is uploading was audio or video so I can save them in their particular folder and play with their specific player.

I would prefer if someone can give solution with javascript or fineuploader core functions but php solution will also works.

PS : I just need a way to do this, rest I'll take care

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best or at least the easiest way to handle this may be to use ffmpeg. For example, `ffmpeg -i file.mp4` will provide a bit of metadata about the file, including streams/tracks. If there are *any* video streams, or if there are *only* audio streams, then the file is *not* a video.

Comment: `Stream #0:0(eng): Video: ...` vs `Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ...`

Answer (score 4):

Tested the below code in latest firefox and chrome, checking using `Video` element of HTML5, not sure if it is a hack, I am checking if the height / width of the video is zero, if yes then audio, else video:

```
function isVideo(url){
  return new Promise(function(res, rej){
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.preload='metadata';
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(evt){
      res(!!(video.videoHeight && video.videoWidth));
      video.src = null;      
    };
    video.src = url;
  });
}
```

usage:

```
isVideo('http://example.com/aa.mp4').then(function(bool){...});
isVideo(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)).then... // for file objects and blobs
```

same with a callback:

```
function isVideo(url, callback){
  return new Promise(function(res, rej){
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.preload='metadata';
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(evt){
      callback(!!(video.videoHeight && video.videoWidth));
      video.src = null;      
    };
    video.src = url;
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks man I'll try to implement it too but currently implemented with ffmpeg but the thing is same in both need to check stream

Comment: well done - thx - works like a charm - from 300MB audio file read just 3MB and get result

Answer (score -2):

If you can get the uploaded file name in one variable assume if it is a variable called `filename` then the following check will give you the solution

`if(filename.split('.').pop().toUpperCase()=="MP4")`

Comment: just extension check will not work in this case, MP4 extension is used by both Audio and Video files